# Mapping from JSON body to model issue because of system naming

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

In the request body I there is a property named `systemDate`. This property is always set to `0` in my model and I thought it was because of the variable type (`long` , `double`, etc) but after I changed the name from `systemDate` to `someDate` in the request body and from `SystemDate` to `SomeDate` in the model class the value is passed from the request body to the model instance just as it is supposed to be.

Why is this happening and is there a way to keep the request json naming and make it passing its value to the model?

```
{  
    "category":"some_category",
    "level":5,
    "source":"some_source",
    "location":"some_location",
    "date":2793455394017,
    "message":"some_message",
    "id":3295830,
    "systemDate":1533114073596991534
}
```

Here is how my model class looks like:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public MyModel()
    {
    }

    public string Category { get; set; }

    public int Level { get; set; }

    public string Source { get; set; }

    public string Location { get; set; }

    public double Date { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public long Id { get; set; }

    public double SystemDate { get; set; }
}
```

And the Controller method:

```
    [HttpPost(EndpointUrlConstants.MY_ENDPOINT)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomething([FromBody] MyModel myModel)
    {
        // Some Code

        return this.Ok();
    }
```

Comment: Your model doesn't specify a `SystemDate` property

Comment: @RuudKobes Sorry, my bad. I have edited the post.

Comment: @stefan.stt It says `SytemDate` is this a typo?

Comment: You still have a typo @stefan.stt, it should be `SystemDate` instead of `SytemDate`, right?

Comment: @phuzi Sory, typo. The problem is still on.

Comment: @stefan.stt I'm not sure if I understood your problem, check my answer. BTW is there any particular reason why the dates are passed as numeric values?

Comment: @RuiJarimba Because the date format is Unix Timestamp

Comment: @stefan.stt got it :-)

Comment: Could you share us a demo project to reproduce your issue? I made a test with `netcoreapp2.0`, I could get result `1.5331140735969915E+18` for `SystemDate`. Here is the screen shot(https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsyeWQ2z51P3hgsPMMDqs4V20pM8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Asp.Net Core`, we could configure the `Json Serialize Settings` by `AddJsonOptions` in `Startup`.

And the root cause for this issue is related with `NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem, but you can control the serialization using attributes, i.e. property names in the json string don't have to match the property names in the model.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public MyModel()
    {
    }

    [JsonProperty("category")]
    public string Category { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("level")]
    public int Level { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("source")]
    public string Source { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("location")]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("date")]
    public double Date { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("systemDate")]
    public double SomeDate { get; set; }
}
```

Test code, using Newtonsoft.Json nuget package:

```
string json = @"{  
    ""category"":""some_category"",
    ""level"":5,
    ""source"":""some_source"",
    ""location"":""some_location"",
    ""date"":2793455394017,
    ""message"":""some_message"",
    ""id"":3295830,
    ""systemDate"":1533114073596991534
}";

MyModel model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(json);
```

Object is deserialized correctly. As you can see, `SomeDate` property in the model is mapped to match `systemDate` property in the json string.

Comment: It is very strange problem. When I use the implicit deserialization it is always passed as `0`, but when I have tried to save the request body as string and then to deserialize it with `JsonConvert` everything works fine. Thanks.

Comment: @stefan.stt `Asp.Net Core` use `JsonConvert` to deserializate the object, I assume it is related with your `AddJsonOptions` in `Startup` or anything else in your project.

Comment: @Edward Actually the problem was with `NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()`. You can post it as an answer and I will accept it so to be useful to others with similar problems.